# Getting database values into a applet

Tags: java, mysql, database, ms-access, applet

I have a access database with table named student And in that there's a `Id` field.I created a Java applet and in that when I input a value for Id in `TextField1` in the applet and press `Display` button,the applet should display the student's other details in TextFields.

Here's my code for the Display button.

```
if(command=="Dispaly"){
    try{
    int stId=Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
        ResultSet result=state.executeQuery("SELECT*FROM student WHERE Id=stId");
```

But this gives an error as Too few parameters.Expected1.

But if i change the query as

```
ResultSet result=state.executeQuery("SELECT*FROM student WHERE Id=3");
```

(That is for the student with id=3) it works fine.
What's wrong with my code? Can someone please show it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query will always generate this SQL "`SELECT*FROM student WHERE Id= stId`"

while what you really need is to substitute it with the value of the stId variable.

so you have to append the stId to the query to be like that `"SELECT*FROM student WHERE Id="+ stId`

Change this line to be ..

```
ResultSet result=state.executeQuery("SELECT*FROM student WHERE Id="+ stId);
```

You can read more about the prepared statments (Dynamic passing the parameters to the query ) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
I hope this could help!

Comment: Yet another database newbie being told to write dynamic SQL instead of doing it the right way and using a parameterized query. -1

Comment: @MuhammadHamed When I try to insert using this preparedStatement I get a error as `driver does not support this function`Here's what I did `String query = "INSERT INTO student (Id,studentName,age)"+ " VALUES(?, ?, ?)"; 
    PreparedStatement state = con.prepareStatement(query);
    state.setInt (1, value1);
    state.setString (2, value2);
    state.setInt  (3, value3);
      
     state.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO student (Id,studentName,age) VALUES ("+value1+","+value2+","+value3+")");`

Comment: You do not have pass the query again .. just
state.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 3):

Your query is failing because the database engine has no way of knowing what `stId` means. You need to pass that value as a *parameter* like so

```java
PreparedStatement state = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student WHERE Id=?");
int stId=Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
state.setInt(1, stId);
ResultSet result=state.executeQuery();
```